# Force mobile UI on Dropbox logon

Tags: webview, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm implementing Dropbox API for a certain second tier mobile platform. The user needs to log on to Dropbox via their Web interface; I create a web view and make it navigate to `https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize`, as per [the docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#authorize). The UI looks like a desktop Web page - with lots of pictorial fluff and hopelessly zoomed out.

On the other hand, on iOS and Android the logon page looks perfectly mobile friendly.

Question - is there a way to explicitly invoke the mobile logon page, the way iOS and Android API's do? An alternative URL, a custom header, a User-Agent string?

My browser control is WebKit-derived - it should understand things like CSS media queries and `<meta viewport>`. But it looks like there aren't any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add ?display=mobile to force the mobile version.

Comment: Works, yay. Where'd you get the info? It's not documented AFAIK.